# Rabbitmq message differentiate with message id based on Java API

Tags: rabbitmq

i would like to publish/produce a message with some message id, like each message has a particular id..And at the consumer end i would like to retrieve the messages by prividing the ID. suppose we have multiple consumers than each one should get only those messages which they requested through the message ids using java. (i hope i am clear enough).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly how a queue Functions you should be looking at Hashtables (key,value) stores like Redis.

A queue is not supposed to have look up features.
One way is the consumers consume messages and remove those only those messages from the Queue, whose UID they want.